# How to submit extjs form without validation

Tags: extjs

In some cases, I want to submit a form without any validation.

Could you guys help me to find a way to implement this in extjs? Even some of the field of the form is not valid, it also needs to be submitted. For example, a form contains a time field.

When I want to update just one radio button in this form, even the date field is invalid, but it also should be submitted.

So how to implement this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

While submitting you form, you can pass false to **clientValidation** config passed during form submission:

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    clientValidation: false,
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    params: {
        newStatus: 'delivered'
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
               Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
        }
    }
});
```

Docs says:

> **clientValidation : Boolean**
> Determines whether a Form's fields are validated in a final call to isValid > > prior to submission. Pass false in the Form's submit options to prevent this.
>
> Defaults to: true